# Bootstrap typeahead: return html

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to return my typeahead results with some html to add links.  I just recently learned about the highlighter function but I'm struggling to return the link properly because I need item.id which is part of my json response.

Here's my script:

```
$('.lookup').typeahead({

  displayText: function(item) {
      return item.label
  },
  afterSelect: function(item) {
      this.$element[0].value = item.value;
       $('#contact_id').val(item.id);
       $('#form_search_contact').submit();
  },
  source: function (query, process) {
    return $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php', { query: query, what: 'location_autocomplete_contacts' }, function(data) {
      process(data);
    })
  },    
  highlighter: function(item) {
      return ('<a href="ajax_selectcontact.php?contact_id='+item.id+'&redirect_to=index.php">appt.</a>->'+ item);
  }


});
```

My json response looks like this:

```
 [{"label":"Contact: Screech Powers-> Powers, Screech: 1980-02-05","value":"Powers, Screech","id":"4258"}]
```

The item.id is not passing into the link I created in my highlighter link.

Also do I still need the display text?

I'd like to have the display text show as the label only, and then when the user highlights over an option, THEN show the info shown in the highlighter part of the script.  If this isn't possible, I'm ok with only showing the highlighter html.

Comment: can you console log item in the highlighter function.

Comment: Just did. It's only: Contact: Screech Powers-> Powers, Screech: 1980-02-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used map as a global object to pull out the id property in the highlighter function. You can press 'a' in the text box. The link will show the id inside.

```js
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
     source:  function (query, process) {
      
    map = {};
  items = [];
    var data =[{"label":"Contact: Screech Powers-> Powers, Screech: 1980-02-05","value":"Powers, Screech","id":"4258"},
    {"label":"Contact: Demo, Screech: 1985-02-05","value":"Powers, Screech","id":"1001"},
    ]
 
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        map[item.label] = item;
        items.push(item.label);
    });
 
    process(items);
    },
    
    highlighter: function(item) {
    
  
    
      return ('<a style="color: red" href="ajax_selectcontact.php?contact_id='+map[item].id+'&redirect_to=index.php">appt.</a>->'+ item);
  }
  
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <br/>
  <h1>Search Dynamic Autocomplete using Bootstrap Typeahead JS</h1> 
   <input class="typeahead form-control" style="margin:0px auto;width:300px;" type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.   Is this the correct way to get my data?
var data = $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php', { query: query, what: 'location_autocomplete_contacts' });  In doing so, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at process(items).

Comment: Not yet. Working on it. I get the typeerror as I explained after your suggestion.

Comment: Ok.  It means that,  the php page is not returning a Json file rather it's returning html.  Please open up browser console and see the network tab,  while doing the type ahead

Comment: Thats weird because I'm getting the same json response as I had before. It looks good to me!  The network tab shows the query passing into the page and the response coming back like json.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing to test this is trying to show an alert if the link is clicked.  The alert never shows either.  With this approach, I could populate hidden form fields in a form and submit it, thus doing the same thing as my original url.

```
$('.lookup').typeahead({
items: '20',
scrollHeight: '100',
autoSelect: true,    
  afterSelect: function(item) {
      this.$element[0].value = map[item].value;
       $('#contact_id').val(map[item].id);
       $('#form_search_contact').submit();
  },
  source: function (query, process) {

      map = {};
      items = [];
      var data = $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php', { query: query, what: 'location_autocomplete_contacts' }, function(data) {

          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
          map[item.label] = item;
          items.push(item.label);
    });

      process(items);
      });

  },
  highlighter: function(item) {
      return ('<a href="#" id="make_appt_link_search">appt.</a>->'+ map[item].label);
  }


 });

 $(".typeahead").on( "click", "li #make_appt_link_search", function(e) 
 {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('');
 });
```